# Programmatically take screenshots on iOS from anywhere

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am currently using this code to capture the screen:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(keyWindow.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(keyWindow.bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It works fine from the Springboard but in an opened application, there is no image created.  The key window and [UIScreen mainScreen] should work from anywhere or should they not?

Do I have to get more specific and somehow use the specific window that the current app is using?

Comment: Are you trying to get screenshots of other apps?

Comment: I'm making an Activator listener and when called, the code runs to get a screenshot.  When called from an opened application, the image is not produced.

Comment: Your code gets the screen for your app. If your app is in the background it is not displaying anything on the screen, so no image. That is my best guess anyway.

Comment: No I run this with an open application

Comment: When you say open you mean the current active app in the foreground?

Comment: Yes, I have the app open and can interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a silly answer, but are you sure that the view is loaded when you try to capture the key window?

HOpe this helps.

Comment: Thats not an answer, thats a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Jailbroken iOS only:

```
// fwd declare a private function
UIKIT_EXTERN CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();

// grab screen image from framebuffer.
// this grabs everything: status bar included
CGImageRef ref = UIGetScreenImage();

// create a UIImage out of CoreGraphics object
// at this point img contains your screenshot
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

// release temp object
CGImageRelease(ref);
```

Comment: You need to add some description like how work this code.... it's good for you and others also...:-)....cheers

Comment: Obviously you need to do it from a Mobile Substrate addon (tweak)